# How to compare the output of crypt() to a cmd line input for cracking passwords in C

Tags: c, string, cs50, string-literals, crypt

I'm taking the cs50x intro to comp sci course and one of the exercises is to decrypt a password that was encrypted using the crypt(3) function.

They've simplified the requirements by setting the hypothetical that the password can only be 5 characters long and every character will be an uppercase or lowercase letter.

I've hit a roadblock with encrypting and comparing and am unsure how to move forward.

**Summary below.**

I've made it as far as cycling through all possible variations of A-Z and a-z for A, AA, AAA, AAAA, and AAAAA.

And I can compare that to user input from argv.

Now I'm trying to have argv be a hash and compare that to the hash of ( possible password from above)

**Where I'm struggling -->**

How I imagine the code should work

1. receive argv[1] and identify salt.
2. generate password
3. hash password with crypt()
4. compare password-hash vs argv[1]
5. if not a match, generate new password and repeat until match.

**What's not working -->**

storing the password hash for comparison and updating the password hash with new hash after manipulation.

**What I think I understand -->**

1. The hash is stored as a string literal.
2. You can't update string literals.
3. I need to assign a variable to store the hash in order to compare it to argv.

What am I missing? What should I read up on to move forward?

thanks in advance!

Comment: If you share the code you've written, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @CinderBiscuits I know. My dilemma here is that I don't want to incorrectly influence any other cs50x student who is looking for solutions. So I thought I could try to generalize first.

Comment: It's admiral you don't want to unfairly affect your fellow students, but until you show us what code you've already written, you're unlikely to get an answer to your question

Comment: String literals have a static storage duration, they exist for the lifetime of the program. You can't update or even write a string literal during runtime. The `crypt(3)` function returns a pointer to the generated password. This password is stored in a static segment of data, but it is not a string literal, and it is overwritten with every call to `crypt(3)`.

You can just assign a pointer to the `crypt(3)` result and reassign it every time you call `crypt(3)` if you don't want to do that, you can copy the result using `strcpy(3)` to a `char` array and use the `char` array.

Comment: Thanks @CinderBiscuits - how do I assign a pointer to the crypt(3) results?

and can I compare that pointer to argv[1]?

Or would I need to also make a pointer for argv[1] to compare the both of them for equality?

I've spent some time reading up on pointers today, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to set the pointer to the value of the function. 

Because as far as I understand crypt(3) already returns a pointer to the result.

Comment: `char *result = crypt(key, salt);`

Comment: A pointer can be assigned to a pointer. They will both return the same address. Yes, I would suggest that you also create a pointer to `argv[1]`, it will make your code easier to understand. Make sure to null check both as well (`crypt(3)` will return a null pointer if it fails, and `argv[1]` may not exist)

Comment: What am I doing wrong? @CinderBiscuits

`char p[] = "A";
    char salt[3];
    salt[0] = s[0];
    salt[1] = s[1];

    char *compare = crypt(p, salt);
    p[0] = 66;

    *compare = crypt(p, salt); `

crack.c:28:14: error: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'char' from 'char *'; dereference with * [-Werror,-Wint-conversion]
    *compare = crypt(p, salt);

Comment: You don't dereference the pointer to reassign it. `compare = crypt(p, salt);`

Comment: @CinderBiscuits Thank you so much! that worked. I'm not entirely clear on the details, but I can atleast move forward with the hwk assignment. 

To get a better understanding of what I was doing wrong, what would you recommend I read up on?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: I would suggest reading up on pointers and memory allocation. https://pebble.gitbooks.io/learning-c-with-pebble/content/chapter08.html

Comment: @CinderBiscuits thanks I'll give it a read. 

Really quickly though - I ran into another issue. 

`char *p = "A";
p[0] = 65;`

gives me a segmentation fault. 

Why can't I do that?

P is the variable I am using to store the autogenerated password. So it will cycle through the alphabet.

Comment: `char *p = "A";` Is a pointer to a string literal. String literals are stored statically in a read only part of the program so they cannot be reassigned. `p[0] = 65;` is an attempt to write to that read only address. You either allocate writable storage space for your pointer to point to (a pointer is a reference to a memory address, after all.) This can be done using `malloc(3)` and similar to store in heap, or automatically allocated on the stack with the form `char p[6]`, `6` being the length of the string (including null terminator).

Comment: In either case, you will not assign a string literal to them directly using `=` you will need to use a function like `strcpy(3)` to copy the characters from the string literal into the char array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the result of `crypt(3)` to a `char*` and reference the hash from the pointer:

```
char *compare = crypt(p, salt);
compare = crypt(p, salt);
```

Since `crypt(3)` has its own static data space it will rewrite on every call to it, you may want to copy the hash to your program's space using a char array and `strcpy(3)`

```
char hash[256]; // arbitrary length, enough to store the hash without overflowing
char *compare = crypt(p, salt);
strcpy(hash, compare);
```

or more tersely,

```
char hash[256];
strcpy(hash, crypt(p, salt));
```

In this way, `hash` won't be overwritten when `crypt(3)` is called again.

Remember to null check the result of `crypt(3)` before using it as it may return a null pointer on error.

```
char *compare = crypt(p, salt);
compare = crypt(p, salt);
if (compare) { // null check
    if (strcmp(compare, input) == 0) }
        printf("%s is identical to %s!", compare, input);
    } else {
        printf("%s does not match %s."), compare, input);
    }
}
```

Since you are working with c-strings and we know they are null terminated, it's possible to compare them using `strcmp(3)`, if you were with raw bytes, or char arrays not guaranteed to be null terminated, it would be better to use `memcmp(3)` for comparison.